# Delete an item from list in react native and update the new list

Tags: react-native, arraylist

I am trying to make a To-Do app in react native. When deleting an item from the list and then try to add a new task in the list, the whole list gets render even the deleted items also. below is my code

```
arr = []
  state = {
    text : "",
    item : [
      {id:0,data:"Loading ......"}
    ]
  }

  del = (id,data) => {
    this.setState({
      item: this.state.item.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    })
   }
  storeData = async () => {
    this.arr.push({id:Math.random().toString(),data: this.state.text})
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(this.arr))
    this.setState({
      item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'))
    })
  }
  
   
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'))
    })
    this.arr = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'))
  }
```

I even tried to envoke `storeData` function inside the `del` function but that is not working.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: check this line  item: this.state.item.filter(item => item.id !== id). 
maybe your filter condition not working

Comment: it is working, the item gets deleted after click but again when a new item is added then all the previous items even deleted one gets added

Comment: show the code where you add new item

Comment: storeData function is used to add a task and del is the function the delete.please refer the code above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this.arr to store item to store in AsyncStorage, but in del function, you forgot to remove item from this.arr. In this case, just use this.state.item is enough, you don't need this.arr

```
 del = async (id,data) => {
   try {
    const newItem = this.state.item.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(newItem))
    this.setState({
      item: newItem
     })
    } catch(err) {}
  }

  storeData = async () => {
    try {
      const newItem = [
         ...this.state.item, 
         {id:Math.random().toString(),data: this.state.text}
      ];
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(newItem))
      this.setState({
        item: newItem
      })
    } catch(err) {}
  }
  
   
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'))
    })
  }
```

Comment: When I reload the app then the previous data gets cleared and list becomes empty. I want to store previous list items on reloading the app.

Comment: that's why you're using AsynStorage, but this.arr is uneccessary

Comment: I mean to say that the function storeData you posted didn't work as expected. If the app is restarted the list must hold previous state when it was closed but in contrary to that list becomes empty.

Comment: sorry, I forget for replace this.arr to newItem

Comment: You mean like this ```storeData = async () => {
    try {
      const newItem = [
         ...this.state.item, 
         {id:Math.random().toString(),data: this.state.text}
      ]; this.arr.push(newItem);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(newItem))
      this.setState({
        item: newItem
      })
    } catch(err) {}
  }```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217528/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-and-cuongtd).